# How to hide and show a panel by clicking a button in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have three panels and three buttons. Upon clicking button1 I want to show Panel1 and hide Panel2 and Panel3.

The same process with the other buttons and panels. How can I do this?

I'm using a Window Forms application written in C#/.NET. This code is not working very well, because only two panels are showing.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlItems.Visible = true;
    pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
    pnlPOS.Visible = false;
}

private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlItems.Visible = true;
    pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
    pnlPOS.Visible = false;
}

private void btnCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlCustomer.Visible = true;
    pnlItems.Visible = false;
    pnlPOS.Visible = false;
}

private void btnPOS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlPOS.Visible = true;
    pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
    pnlItems.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? I mean what does it do **vs** what you want it to do?

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong with this, maybe you are missing add Click events to those buttons or specific one

Comment: this code is not working very well because only two panels are showing

Comment: In every Panel has textbox, comboBox and button

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code for the view?

Comment: Please put more information in your question (for example here in the comments you stated whats the problem, not in the question)

Comment: Can you show me other alternative way

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, so what ever the problem its not evident. This is the problem with writing code, things never work, you need to learn how to reduce complexity until it works and figure it out and learn how to debug your application. for all we know you haven't hooked up all your button click events

Comment: @SwimmingPool just because someone asks you to upvote doesn't mean you should. Have you tried the solution? Did it change anything? Did you understand why?

Comment: Which 2 panels work? Have you checked to make sure that when adding the panels to your form you didn't drag one panel inside one of the other ones? You likely have the non-working panel as a control of one of the other panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlItems.Visible = true;
    pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
    pnlPOS.Visible = false;
}

private void btnItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pnlItems.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlItems.Visible = true;
        pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
        pnlPOS.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnCustomers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pnlCustomer.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlCustomer.Visible = true;
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
        pnlPOS.Visible = false;
    }
}

private void btnPOS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(pnlPOS.Visible != true)
    {
        pnlPOS.Visible = true;
        pnlCustomer.Visible = false;
        pnlItems.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Here I have updated the conditional statement for if your panel is not visible then act. I hope this will work.

Comment: yeah that way is also possible.

Comment: Why would ***adding a condition to do something*** make it work when just ***doing it*** doesn't work? I'm puzzled as how does this answer the question

Comment: may for new comers this way is simple. Solution should be understandable. Person who asked seems a beginner at programming.

Comment: problem was that the process is working but not completely so i had tried to make it happen at all scenarios.

Comment: This is incomprehensible: *"...updated the conditional statement for if your panel is not visible then act"*. Can you fix it?